# Yolo8 not working with Pi Camera Module 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I am currently using Raspberry Pi 4 on Bullseye. I have connected the pi camera to the raspberry and when I test the camera with "libcamera-hello" it works, but when I want to use it locally with yolov8 for object detection and test it with models it throws an error. This is the code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
from PIL import Image
import cv2


model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")

model.predict(source="0", show = True)
```

This is the error:

```
[ WARN:0@11.867] global cap_v4l.cpp:2060 getProperty
VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): Unable to get camera FPS Traceback (most
recent call last):   File "/home/pi/Documents/TihaNEW/yolo/test.py",
line 8, in <module>
    model.predict(source="0", show = True)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py",
line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py",
line 254, in predict
    return self.predictor.predict_cli(source=source) if is_cli else self.predictor(source=source, stream=stream)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py",
line 195, in __call__
    return list(self.stream_inference(source, model, *args, **kwargs))  # merge list of Result into one   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py",
line 35, in generator_context
    response = gen.send(None)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py",
line 227, in stream_inference
    self.setup_source(source if source is not None else self.args.source)   File
"/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py",
line 208, in setup_source
    self.dataset = load_inference_source(source=source, imgsz=self.imgsz, vid_stride=self.args.vid_stride)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/data/build.py",
line 159, in load_inference_source
    dataset = LoadStreams(source, imgsz=imgsz, vid_stride=vid_stride)   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/data/loaders.py",
line 65, in __init__
    raise ConnectionError(f'{st}Failed to read images from {s}') ConnectionError: 1/1: 0... Failed to read images from 0
```

Any ideas how to fix it. I saw that there are some problems with V4L2, but didn't find or understand how to fix the problem for YOLO?

Thanks in advance.